# Release key to sign several Android apps

Tags: android, key, signing

Can you use one my-release-key.keystore to sign different apps or do you need a different my-release-key.keystore for each app?

Comment: I think you can and sometimes you have to e.g. when both applications should share data if I recall correctly - this info is actually in most of books for teaching programming in android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is lifted straight from the Android documentation - bolded the important bit.

> Some aspects of application signing may affect how you approach the
>   development of your application, especially if you are planning to
>   release multiple applications.
>
> In general, **the recommended strategy for all developers is to sign all
>   of your applications with the same certificate**, throughout the
>   expected lifespan of your applications. There are several reasons why
>   you should do so:
>
> - Application upgrade – As you release updates to your application, you
>     will want to continue to sign the updates with the same certificate or
>     set of certificates, if you want users to upgrade seamlessly to the
>     new version. When the system is installing an update to an
>     application, it compares the certificate(s) in the new version with
>     those in the existing version. If the certificates match exactly,
>     including both the certificate data and order, then the system allows
>     the update. If you sign the new version without using matching
>     certificates, you will also need to assign a different package name to
>     the application — in this case, the user installs the new version as a
>     completely new application.
> - Application modularity – The Android
>     system allows applications that are signed by the same certificate to
>     run in the same process, if the applications so requests, so that the
>     system treats them as a single application. In this way you can deploy
>     your application in modules, and users can update each of the modules
>     independently if needed.
> - Code/data sharing through permissions – The
>     Android system provides signature-based permissions enforcement, so
>     that an application can expose functionality to another application
>     that is signed with a specified certificate. By signing multiple
>     applications with the same certificate and using signature-based
>     permissions checks, your applications can share code and data in a
>     secure manner.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: I couldn't find your quote in the current documentation, but I did find it at http://my.fit.edu/~vkepuska/ece5570/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/docs/tools/publishing/app-signing.html, but that might be out of date.

Answer (score 1):

You just need the one key.

Read more about it here [Android App Signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)